# need a help to optimize ORACLE SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

Can someone please help me optimize following query?

This query fetches records from many tables as described on JOINS, it takes too much time because of following Joins:

I takes too much time to execute both joins as shown below.
Is there any way through which I can implement in better way?

```
 SELECT......... .....
 LEFT OUTER JOIN .....
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
       SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C
       from ABC
       where (A,B,C )  not in 
       (
       select A,B,C from 
              ( 
                  SELECT A,B,C,count(*) 
                  FROM ABC
                  group by  A,B,C                 
                  having count(*) >1 
              )
       ) 
     )      temp1       ON condition1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
       SELECT DISTINCT X,Y,Z      from XYZ
       where (X,Y,Z  )  not in 
       (
       select X,Y,Z  from 
              ( 
                  SELECT X,Y,Z ,count(*) 
                  FROM XYZ
                  group by  X,Y,Z                  
                  having count(*) >1 
              )
       ) 
     )      temp2       ON condition2 .... ... LEFT OUTER JOIN ....... Where
```

Some condition

Query work smoothly if I remove two joins shown above.

Comment: There is no need for `distinct`, because previous `count` eliminated duplicates. And you can change these subqueries to [analytic versions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=adeaed4e86874df506056a4b1a31a1c4).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that mentioned code block is giving you the performance impact then you can use following code. I have replaced your inner query with my version. -- See inline comments.

```
SELECT......... .....
 LEFT OUTER JOIN .....
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
--      (
--       SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C
--       from ABC
--       where (A,B,C )  not in 
--       (
--       select A,B,C from 
--              ( 
--                  SELECT A,B,C,count(*) 
--                  FROM ABC
--                  group by  A,B,C                 
--                  having count(*) >1 
--              )
--       ) 
--     )      
                --
                -- commented above inner query and 
                --
                -- added following inner query
                --
                (SELECT A,B,C 
                  FROM ABC
                  group by  A,B,C                 
                  having count(*) = 1)
                --
                --
     temp1       ON condition1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
--      (
--       SELECT DISTINCT X,Y,Z      from XYZ
--       where (X,Y,Z  )  not in 
--       (
--       select X,Y,Z  from 
--              ( 
--                  SELECT X,Y,Z ,count(*) 
--                  FROM XYZ
--                  group by  X,Y,Z                  
--                  having count(*) >1 
--              )
--       ) 
--     )      
                --
                -- commented above inner query and 
                --
                -- added following inner query
                --
                (SELECT X,Y,Z
                  FROM XYZ
                  group by  X,Y,Z                  
                  having count(*) = 1 )
                --
                --
     temp2       ON condition2 .... ... LEFT OUTER JOIN ....... Where
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I have solved OP's lengthy query with a simpler version that will save time in execution -- @Rob

Comment: The question is off topic here and should not be answered. Not all questions should be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer The question is now closed and will be deleted along with your answer.

Comment: Yes, I can understand.